# My code returns an error when trying to split a vector

Tags: java

I have a problem with a Java code and I can't solve it, I have a Vector with 3.529 .txt files and I wanted to split it into 6 other vectors. I'm using the code below to split the vector. What am I doing wrong?

```
int cut = filesToProcess.size() / 6;
List<List<File>> arrays = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < filesToProcess.size(); i = i + cut) {
   arrays.add(filesToProcess.subList(i, i + cut)); //line 35
}
```

[image: When I run the code I get this error]

Comment: 3500 is not an exact multiple of 6.  Think about what will happen on the last iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

> arrays.add(filesToProcess.subList(i, i + cut));

In you for statement, i < fileToProcess.size(), so if i == fileToProcess.size() - 1, i + cut is definitely out of range.

The idea to solve this problem is to change the for statement to:

```
i < filesToProcess.size() - cut.
```

Edit: as passer-by said, divide int may have decimal loss so you can’t cut perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your approach:

1. 3529 / 6 is not even so you'll end up with 7 vectors instead of 6. So you need to round up your `cut` with `int cut = (int) Math.ceil((double) filesToProcess.size() / 6);`
2. When you have uneven division, your last vector won't have the same number of items as the others so you will always get `IndexOutOfBounds`. This is clearly stated in your exception: "toIndex: 4116" where `.subList()` is trying to get items up to index 4116. To fix this, you need to check the "to' part of `.subList()` to make sure it's not too large.

```
int cut = (int) Math.ceil((double)items.size() / 6);
List<List<File>> arrays = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < filesToProcess.size(); i = i + cut) {
   arrays.add(filesToProcess.subList(i, Math.min(i + cut, filesToProcess.size())));
}
```

With this, you should get the following split:

```
Vector = 1 => size = 589
Vector = 2 => size = 589
Vector = 3 => size = 589
Vector = 4 => size = 589
Vector = 5 => size = 589
Vector = 6 => size = 584
```